# Fast accurate sparse svd library?

Tags: java, c++, c, matrix, svd

I'm looking for a fast svd library, in either c, c++ or java.  Ultimately I'm using Java, but I'm very comfortable using jna to wrap c++, eg http://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen

I'm looking for a fast svd library that will handle sparse matrices.  To keep this objective, so that the question doesn't get marked as too subjective, let's say:

- targeting use with news20.binary , eg from http://mldata.org/repository/data/viewslug/news20binary/
- how fast does it take to run?
- how much variance is conserved, eg for an S matrix of size 6 or 20?

I looked around at a few libraries and found:

- matlab: super fast, about 10 seconds, but it's not really a 'library' as such.  average squared projection error: 0.93
- redsvd: super fast, about 1 second to run, for 6 features, but the average squared projection error is 0.97, which is very high
- Eigen's svd is both very slow, and only for dense matrices
- svdlibc: ran for 28 minutes before I stopped it; I guess it's calculating the full S, rather than just the first 6 features or so

Basically, I'm looking for a library that gives about the same speed and average squared projection error as matlab, or at least, somewhat comparable.

Comment: What algorithm are you looking for ? [Randomized PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html) (not c++/java but I think the right algorithm) for 20 newsgroups x 10k features, 6 PCs --> `7.0 sec  pca explained_variance_ratio_ .79 .062 .044 .039 .031 .03`.

Comment: I'm suprised Eigen's SVD is so slow. I have never used Eigen for this. Has it improved since you last asked this question?

Comment: BTW, [when are you going to implement the sparse solvers in JEigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046585/cholmod-in-java/30526005#30526005)?

Comment: @Z boson, seems like you've already implemented this.  Want to send a pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, svdlibc is the best library of those options.  I've dug a bit through its code before and I don't believe it's calculating the full S matrix (i.e., it is a true "thin svd").  If you can control the matrix representation on disk, svdlibc performs much faster when using the sparse binary input format due to the significantly lower I/O overhead.

The S-Space Package provided an [executable jar](http://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/downloads/detail?name=svd.jar&can=2&q=#makechanges) around the SVDLIBJ java port of SVDLIBC.  However, they found it had different results than SVDLIBC for certain input solutions.

Comment: Ok.  Do you know how I can request the command-line version to only return the first 6 features, rather than calculating the whole matrix?